# My edits are not saved

Tags: pages, the-content, wp-editor

Everything used to be fine, but now for some reason I’m editing the record, but the old content remains, the new one for some reason does not appear.
For example, I have everything stored in the pages and there I do the editing (I use custom fields) and save it, and on the page after the reload all the same content. Why is this happening ? even if you delete everything, everything remains the same on the page. I display information on the screen + - everywhere so. Doesn't see any change at all

```
<?php if( have_rows('question_section') ): ?>
                <?php while( have_rows('question_section') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="question_to_you_bl">
                                <?php echo get_sub_field('question_section_description_lb'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block offset-lg-1">
                            <div class="question_to_you_br">
                                <?php echo get_sub_field('question_section_description_rb'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Take look at the php error_log (or debug.log) and the browser console.

Comment: Have you checked in the database to see whether the changes are saved to the postmeta table? That will tell you whether it's a problem saving, or retrieving. It could be as simple as some layer of caching that needs to be flushed.

Comment: @WebElaine Saves on a local server, but on a simple server I don’t know how to check

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a simple server. If you're using Apache or Nginx you can usually use phpMyAdmin. Depending on your host they may have some different way to access the database. But in a case like this where you're not seeing the end result you want it's important to determine where the breakdown is - whether it's saving and not getting displayed, or not even being saved at all. With it working fine on localhost I would suspect caching on the server.

Comment: @WebElaine there are problems on web hosting

Comment: I delete content (posts) from posts . I deleted everything that could be from the section post and everything was deleted on the page too. And now my information is in the page section, how can I display it from there?